# Using regext to remove substring of image name

Tags: java, regex

I have this image copy method that uses the name of the image being copied for the new version. If I am copying the same image often it will add (integer) behind the image name: like image.jpg becomes image(1).jpg. Now I am trying to use regex to replace the (int) part but I am not quite getting how to do it.

```
imageName.replaceAll(["(]\\d[)]","");
```

But does this only delete (1) but not if there were like two digits (12)?

Comment: Your quotes are a bit off (after your opening bracket instead of ahead), but are you looking for: `\\(\\d+\\)`??. Not a `Java` guy, so might be wrong on the double backslashes...

Answer (score 1):

```
"image(1).jpg".replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)", "")
```

[RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/537dv)

The key bit to this is the `+` operator which matches one or more element of the preceding expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for the same
imageName.replaceAll("[(]\d*\d[)]", "");